# What's wrong with my [UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to get my chat bubble image file to have a more rounded edge. Right now this is what it looks like:

[image]

And this is with

```
resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 58, 22)
```

The image file that I am using looks like this

[image]

I've tried a lot of inset values but I can't figure out which one would work. Thanks!

Comment: what exactly does "more rounded" mean? anyway, `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` won't affect the edges, so it is just not the right tool.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image?

Comment: 60 x 92 are the dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the cap insets cannot change the rounding of the corners. You need to change the original image (the one that you show second in your question).